# Is it possible to use google recaptcha v2 without images verification

Tags: recaptcha

I know that google **reCaptcha v2** need user interaction for verification. But I want implement this way there will be a **checkbox** click but no **images verification**. Want only checkbox click verification. How can I implement this? Suggest me some solution.